# What does כתר"ה stand for?

Tags: acronyms

What does כתר"ה mean?  It's mentioned very often in Igros Moshe, often in reference to the one who asked the shailah  e.g. "שאל כתר"ה"

Answer (score 16):

It's a term of respect when referring to someone: [כבוד תורתו הרמה](http://www.kizur.co.il/search_word.php?abbr=%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%A8%22%D7%94&m=22)

Comment: Wouldn't it then be כתה"ר?

Comment: כבוד תורת הרב???